# substrate-front-end-template, yarn install failure

Tags: substrate-front-end

tom@tompc:~/Downloads/substrate-front-end-template$ yarn install
00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'install'

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Comment: voting to close as this is not a substrate question.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to an incorrect yarn version i believe.
I fixed it on Ubuntu 20.04 by installing node and yarn in the following way:

```
# Install Nodejs
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash - &&
sudo apt update &&
sudo apt install nodejs &&
sudo apt install build-essential

# Install Yarn
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add - && 
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list &&
sudo apt update &&
sudo apt install yarn &&
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                        
Hit:4 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease          
Hit:5 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease        
Ign:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x jammy InRelease

Comment: Err:7 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 23.213.230.141 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: ## Confirming "jammy" is supported...

+ curl -sLf -o /dev/null 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x/dists/jammy/Release'

## Your distribution, identified as "jammy", is not currently supported, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support

Comment: Just saying - this is a security anti-patern to just `sudo` something you found `curl`ed... I think I know where you are getting this from, but please do update on the source from where to get the official install from  -- also voting to close as this is not a substrate question